# Объеденить 2 типа без повторений typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть два массива

```
const a = [
  {name: '1', surname: '11'},
  {name: '2', surname: '22'},
  {name: '4', surname: '44'}
] as const

const b = [
  {name: '1', surname: '11'},
  {name: '2', surname: '22'},
  {name: '3', surname: '33'}
] as const
```

Мне нужно динамически получить тип в котором не будет повторений:

```
type q = {name: "1" | "2" | "3" | "4", surname: "11" | "22" | "33" | "44"}[]
```

Я делаю так

```
type q = typeof a | typeof b
```

Но это получается два типа, или то или то, а мне нужен один, где будут собраны все не повторяющиеся значения (порядок не важен). Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Это конечно интересная разминка для ума, но какой в этой задаче вообще смысл?

Comment: @Alexey Ten как оказалось его нет